# Checking saml responses in OpenAM

Tags: openam, opensso

I'm new to **OpenAM**. i have configured openAM as SP and federated it with a remote IDP using SAML. everything works fine but i wonder where can i check the SAML responses that comes from the IDP. I verified all the logs but nothing found . Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the SAML Response as URL parameters.  We need to retrieve it from openAM and decode it ,

```
 String samlResponse = request.getParameter("SAMLResponse");
```

Answer (score 1):

Enable message level debugging 
http://openam.example.com:8080/openam/Debug.jsp

and under your Openam home OPENAM_HOME/log folder you should see files 
which are named as 
SAML2.access-06.20.13-08.52
SAML2.access-06.20.13-11.52
SAML2.error-06.20.13-15.42

In these files you should see saml response in the form

Some more info at 
http://openam.forgerock.org/openam-documentation/openam-doc-source/doc/admin-guide/index/chap-monitoring.html#log-mgmt

-Rama

Answer (score 0):

try saml tracer addon <strike>im tomcat</strike> in firefox.

Comment: Do you mean this Firefox plugin? https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saml-tracer/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I enabled the debug mode to message level in the console . All responses are getting stored in the debug->federation file but if need that in my application any way to retrieve the SAML Attributes into to my application

Comment: well this depends on the application I guess, but I think theyre buried in the requests and I think openam has a way to get them. Somewhere along the line you typecast an httprequest into an AuthnRequest. good luck man. Yea, i meant the firefox addon :D They both just sound like airplane names to me.